# bash function non-zero exit code

Tags: bash, error-handling, exit

In the function "handleExit" below, the exitCode is zero, ie, "0".  i want it to be "1".  My function called "exit 1".  What do I need to do in order to detect that the function "writeToErr" had a non-zero status.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

logError() {
  awk " BEGIN { print \"$@\" > \"/dev/fd/2\" }"
}

function writeToErr ()  {
    echo "standard out"
    logError "standard err"
    exit 1
}

function wrapper () {
    writeToErr >>output.log 2>&1
}

function handleExit () {
    echo "handle exit"
    exitCode=$?
    if [ $exitCode -eq "0" ]
     then
        echo "No problem"
     else
        echo "$0 exited unexpectedly with status:$exitCode"
        exit 1
     fi
}

trap wrapper EXIT
handleExit >>output.log 2>&1
```

And here are the contents of "output.log":

```
handle exit
No problem
standard out
standard err
```

Comment: Get your code checked at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: @codeforester Thanks for the site.  Unfortunately, it didn't catch the errors and pointed out something that is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You run `handleExit` before you run `wrapper`, so it hasn't failed yet.
2. `handleExit` checks the exit code of `echo`

Without a description of what you're trying to do, I'm guessing you wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

logError() {
    # A better way to write to stderr
    echo "$*" >&2
}

function writeToErr ()  {
    echo "standard out"
    logError "standard err"
    exit 1
}

function wrapper () {
    writeToErr >>output.log 2>&1
}

function handleExit () {
    # Get exit code of the previous command, instead of echo
    exitCode=$?
    echo "handle exit"
    if [ $exitCode -eq "0" ]
     then
        echo "No problem"
     else
        echo "$0 exited unexpectedly with status:$exitCode"
        exit 1
     fi
}

# Call handler on exit, so it has something to handle
trap handleExit EXIT
wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated!